# Pascal's triangle/line

Tags: python, recursion

I'm writing a code for homework, it needs t o output the values for pascal's triangle, but not in a triangle. for instance I input

```
pascalLine(2)
```

it outputs:

```
[1,2,1]
```

and for:

```
pascalLine(4)
```

it outputs:

```
[1,4,6,4,1]
```

I currently have this code and I believe it is far from complete, because It outputs a triangle.

```
def pascalLine(n):
  for rownum in range (n):
      newValue=1
      PrintingList = list()
      for iteration in range (rownum):
          newValue = newValue * ( rownum-iteration ) * 1 / ( iteration + 1 )
          PrintingList.append(int(newValue))
      print(PrintingList)
  print()
```

Comment: "it needs t o output the values for pascal's triangle, but not in a triangle" - I'm not really sure what your desired output is here.

Comment: @millimoose: I think the `[1,2,1]` and `[1,4,6,4,1]` the OP gives are examples of the desired output.  I.e. the function should return the nth row of Pascal's triangle as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your original code to calculate row `n` is correct, you can just get rid of the outer loop:

```
def pascalLine(n):
    newValue=1
    row = [newValue]
    for i in range (n):
        newValue = (newValue * (n-i)) / ( i + 1 )
        row.append(newValue)

    print(row)
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this simple algorithm for computing an arbitrary row without having to compute the entire triangle:

```
def pascal_row(n):
    row = [1]

    for col in range(1, n):
        row.append(row[-1] * (n - col) / col)

    return row
```

Comment: the solution doesn't give `n-th` row of the PT, rather gives `(n-1)th` row. by wikipedia definition, the `1st` row is considered `0-th` row.

Comment: @kmonsoor: The rows correspond to powers of `(x + y)`. Since `(x + y)^0 = 1`, the 0th row will be `1`.

Comment: @kmonsoor: Numberings in mathematics are somewhat arbitrary, so there's no "right" answer.